# Is there a way to create or update notes for the new rich Notes App in iOS 9?

Tags: evernote, ios9

I want to create an app which generate content as notes. EverNote has an api for that. Is it possible to create the new rich text iOS 9 notes from my app? I haven't found anything about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no simple way to do that now, as there isn't an API for the notes app. It's possible that apple will release one later, however that's probably not going to happen, as they don't usually do release API's. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you, I have had hopes, that the new notes app get an API like the contacts app. Notes taking should be an infrastructure asset.